# Proof by induction ${n\choose k }\le n^k$

Tags: induction

Ok, so the question is to prove by induction that:

$${n \choose k} \le n^k$$

Where $N$ and $k$ are integers, $k \le n$;

How do I approach this? Do i choose a $n$ and a $k$ to form my base case?

Comment: hint: ${n\choose k} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)}{k!}$

Answer (score 2):

While there are various ways to approach this, I would recommend fixing (an arbitrary) $n$ and inducting on $k$. So your base case would then be to show that $\binom{n}{0} \leq n^0$. To do the inductive step, figure out what you would need to multiply $\binom{n}{k-1}$ by to get $\binom{n}{k}$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove this for all $n$ and all $k$, right? Then, to do it by induction, you must take an arbitrary $n$ and then induct on $k$.

Comment: There is no need to induct on both $k$ and $n$. Actually induction on $n$ seems pretty difficult.

Comment: You're right. We can just induct on $k$ for arbitrary $n$